# how do I trigger a workflow dispatch event with gh api with inputs

Tags: github-actions

so right now I have:

gh api --method POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/workflows/30721645/dispatches -F run_id=${{ github.run_id }}

my workflow_dispatch event takes run_id as input, but the problem is that I get invalid_key for this request, how do I properly pass in the run_id to gh api?

Comment: You could use an action to perform this operation for you, check [this one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch) from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more tricky as you have to pass a JSON to `gh api` and you also need to pass a `ref`.

This should work:

```
jq -n '{"ref":"main","inputs":{"run_id":"${{github.run_id}}"}}' | gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" --method POST /repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/workflows/30721645/dispatches --input -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any `inputs` to pass in and are just running the workflow, you can use:

```bash
gh api /repos/joshjohanning-org/bash-testing/actions/workflows # get id
gh api -X POST /repos/joshjohanning-org/bash-testing/actions/workflows/19595110/dispatches -f ref='main'
```

Otherwise if you want inputs, you can use (similar to @Grzegorz Krukowski above):

```bash
gh api -X POST /repos/joshjohanning-org/bash-testing/actions/workflows/19595110/dispatches \
  --input - <<< '{"ref":"main","inputs":{"message":"all"}}'
```

Or use [gh workflow run](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run):

```bash
gh workflow run -R joshjohanning-org/bash-testing blank.yml 
echo '{"name":"scully", "greeting":"hello"}' | gh workflow run -R joshjohanning-org/bash-testing blank.yml --json
```